# PHP: 'include', but don't run

Tags: php, include

I have a test.php, where I run unit test cases. What I want is to `'include'` certain .php files, but when I do it, they get run. For example, I just need to access certain variables, functions from a .php file, but the whole .php file gets run. In my case, the .php is a huge file. Same thing happening with `'require'`.

Would it be possible to access those .php methods, variables, functions without running them?

Thanks!

Comment: Create the functions in one script(page) then include those in the pages you want to run them on. It sounds like the pages you are including already have calls to the functions in them. If you post an example we could be more specific.

Comment: Put them in a class and run them from there if needed (e.g. `$class->myfunction()`).

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Should have guessed. I will create a new .php file with functions. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what happens when code is included, it is executed as part of the overall script.  You don't "fix this" by some hack which would include code without executing it.  You fix it by organizing your code into invokable units.

In fact, unit testing is a *great* way to start thinking about how to organize your code.  What exactly are you testing?  A class?  A function?  Or just some random block of top-level code in a script somewhere?

If the latter, you are now seeing the problem.  By including that code, you execute it.  Which is outside the context of the test being run.  Instead, you want that code to be in some invokable unit of some sort.  A class, or at the very least a function.

For example, let's say you have a PHP file full of top-level code which performs a variety of tasks.  As you are experiencing, when you include that code all of those tasks are immediately performed.  However, if instead you organize the code in that file into a set of functions, then by including it **all you're doing is defining the functions**.  Consuming code (the unit tests in this case) can then execute those functions as desired, in a controlled and predictable manner.

All the code should do when you include it is *define* the structures.  Then the top-level consuming code should make use of those structures.  Putting all logic into top-level code makes it untestable and unmanageable.

Comment: as you said, 'all you're doing is defining the functions'. But the invocation of those functions will be from other .php file. Am I correct? If yes, I will refactor the code then. thanks David for great answer.

Comment: @joojoo: Correct.  When you include the file, it gets executed.  But if all that file does is define structures of code (classes and functions) then executing it doesn't have any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I was helped. What I will do is I will create a new .php file that will include those required functions and methods that I am going to test.

Update: Seems like I will need to refactor my code, so that I will call required functions and classes from other .php files. This way I 'include' what I want without them getting executed.

Thanks guys for help.