# How can i restrict some php code when including on other php files?

Tags: php, html

For example i have a file `file1.php`:

Now, i have another php file `file2.php` in which i am including in `file1.php`:

```
include "file1.php";
```

I don't want some code to include. Is there any way or function to restrict that code to include?

Comment: you can add a check on the particular code

Comment: Do you practice OOP (Object Oriented Programming)? that is very useful like in your case.

Comment: @OmerMuhammad ... I want to execute all code in file1.php but dont want to load some code in file2.php... If i will use a check or condition, then that code will also not execute in file1.php... and if i make that condition true in file1.php to execute... Then it will become part of file2.php too

Comment: your question is not clear yet to anybody please do some research try it your self then come here to ask a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY this :  In you file1.php add all code in small functions. Then call only those function in file2.php which is needed . You can also use Oops Concept create class and call needed method only .

```
file1.php

method1();
mehtod2();
method3();

file2.php
include file.php

method1();
```

Sorry : You have to use oops concept in PHP .

Comment: why we need a function for this we can put any condition without functions on the plain code.

Comment: But that code will load . Then condition will apply you have to use OOPS in it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert that code block to function(in first file) that you don't want to execute in second file, this will execute only if you call that function otherwise not

Comment: Which function?

Comment: i assume that your code is directly executed, so place it inside some function: `function myCode() {here your code} `. this will execute only if you call 'myCode()' function, otherwise not

Comment: jDeep I think this is not the question or answer he is asking to don't load a particular part of code not all the code

Comment: He said **I don't want some code to include.**. so i thinks he don't want that code execution so i suggest him to convert that **some code** to function then it will not executed automatically

Comment: @Omer Muhammad yes...  I dont want to include a particular code to load in other php file when including

Comment: is there any case or condition when you don't want to load a particular code like some special request etc so that you can put a check/condition to don't load

Comment: jDeep if i will convert that code in a function then file1.php will also not execute that code... I want to execute the particular code in file1.php but not in file2.php

Comment: [THIS ANSWER WILL HELP YOU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33485352/9172680)